# django returning blank page

Tags: python, html, django

i'm not sure what is wrong with the code,

```
forms.py

from django.form import datetime, widgets
import datetime
import calendar
from bootstrap_datepicker.widgets import Datepicker



class DateForm(forms.Form):
    date_1=forms.DateTimeField(widget=DatePicker(
        options={"format": "dd/mm/yyyy",
        "autoclose": True }
        (help_text ='please enter a date',initial= "year/month/day")))
    def cleandate(self):
        c_date=self.cleaned_data['date_1']
        if date < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('date entered has passed'))
        elif date > datetime.date.today():
            return date_1

    def itamdate(forms.Form):
        date_check=calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
        if c_date:
            if date_1==date_check:
                pass
            elif date_1!=date_check:
                raise ValidationError('The Market will not hold today')
            for days in list(range(0,32)):
                for months in list(range(0,13)):
                    for years in list(range(2005,2108)):



views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
import datetime
from .forms import DateForm


def imarket(request):
        #CREATES A FORM INSTANCE AND POPULATES USING DATE ENTERED BY THE USER
    form_class= DateForm 
    form = form_class(request.POST or None)
    if request.method=='POST':
    #checks validity of the form
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('welcome.html'))
    return render(request, 'welcome.html', {'form':form})


welcome.html



 **

{%  extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    <title>welcome</title>

        <form action = "{% url "imarket"}" method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{form}}
            </table>
            <input type ="submit" value= "CHECK"/>
        </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

**
i am trying to implement a datepicker on the welcome page,
i have called the form in the views.py , and returned the "welcome.html" file in the views, but i still get a blank page when i go to the welcome page

i am using django version 1.11.2
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Firstly, please show real code - this is full of syntax errors. Secondly, show *relevant* code; if you are seeing a completely blank page, the problem is not your date picker. You should probably post the base.html - does it have a "content" block?

Comment: yes i have a "base.html", apparently my problem was from the "base.html", i have edited it , and its fine now thanks , i showed all code i felt was relevant because i wasn't sure where the problem was coming from, Thank you

Comment: you are not sending form data with response return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('welcome.html'))

Comment: could you please clarify @Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

[`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) function accept url namespaces, not html templates. Maybe try this:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect('/welcome.html')
```